# How can I stop re-rendering in React when switching between tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `memo` both on outer component as well as on each of the tab components.

Here is my `CommonContainer.tsx`:

```
import { Card, Divider, Grid, Spinner, Tabs, Text } from '@geist-ui/core'
import { memo, useCallback, useState } from 'react'
function CommonContainer(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Card width="100%">
      <Card.Content>
        <Tabs value="p1">
            <Tabs.Item label="P2" value="p2">
              <div >
                <P2QueryTab meta={props.metaList[0]} question={props.question}/>
              </div>
            </Tabs.Item>
            <Tabs.Item label="P1" value="p1">
              <div >
                <P1QueryTab meta={props.metaList[0]} question={props.question}/>
              </div>
            </Tabs.Item>
        </Tabs>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default memo(CommonContainer)
```

Here is my `P2QueryTab.tsx`:

```
import { memo, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import Browser from 'webextension-polyfill'
function P2QueryTab(props: Props) {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState<Answer | null>(null)


  useEffect(() => {
    const port = Browser.runtime.connect()
    const listener = (msg: any) => {
      if (msg.text) {
        setAnswer(msg)
      }
    }
    port.onMessage.addListener(listener)
//This postMessage in turn will call external API to get data 
    port.postMessage({ question: props.meta + ' ' + props.question, displayTab: "Insights" })
    return () => {
      port.onMessage.removeListener(listener)
      port.disconnect()
    }
  }, [props.question])


  if (answer) {
    return (
      <div id="answer" dir="auto">
        {answer.text}
      </div>
    )
  }

  return <p className="animate-pulse">Waiting for P2...</p>
}

export default memo(P2QueryTab)
```

Here is my `P1QueryTab.tsx`:

```
import { memo, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import Browser from 'webextension-polyfill'
function P1QueryTab(props: Props) {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState<Answer | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const port = Browser.runtime.connect()
    const listener = (msg: any) => {
      if (msg.text) {
        setAnswer(msg)
      }
    }
    port.onMessage.addListener(listener)
//This postMessage in turn will call external API to get data 
    port.postMessage({
      question: props.meta + ' ' + props.question
    })
    return () => {
      port.onMessage.removeListener(listener)
      port.disconnect()
    }
  }, [props.question])

  if (answer) {
    return (
      <div id="answer" dir="auto">
        {answer.text}
      </div>
    )
  }

  return <p className="animate-pulse">Waiting for P1...</p>
}

export default memo(P1QueryTab)
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798377/avoid-re-rendering-in-react-when-switching-between-tabs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996194/react-memo-why-is-my-equality-function-not-being-called/58997083#58997083) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873359/react-memo-not-calling-comparison-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868907/how-to-use-reacts-built-in-react-memo-comparison-function) but still my problem is unsolved.

EDIT:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947407/865220) answer doesn't rely on `memo` and does the css trick explicitly himself. Not sure his `Typography` component uses any memorisation at all. But before going that route I need to understand why don't `memo` work in my case, why isn't the custom comparator even getting called.

Comment: @Mulan cleaned up as per your request. no change in behaviour yet

Comment: `Tabs` from `@geist-ui/core` just remove the components instead of hiding them with css. `memo` changes nothing here. I can't see anything in the documentation that would override this behaviour

Comment: @Konrad I see, is there any Tabs library which suits me better .

Comment: @Konrad I changed to most popular Tabs lib for react ie [react-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabs). This does `display:none` css trick with the outer `TabPanel` div but the entire subtree seems to be removed here as well ?

Comment: @Konrad I don't think this is a Tab makers functionality, React itself might be cleaning itself off the very moment you navigate away, so it doesn't even keep hope to check if `memo` would work.

Comment: @Mulan most people facing this issue is due to `key` but  I don't have `key`, I have only 2 `props`: `meta` and `question`

Comment: @Konrad [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947407/865220) answer doesn't rely on `memo` and does the css trick himself. Not sure his `Typography` uses any memorisation at all. But before going that route I need to understand why don't `memo` work , why isn't custom comparator even getting called.

Comment: Because `memo` is used to protect from rerendering, not remounting. Your components get destroyed and created again when the tab changes

Comment: @Konrad so what's the moral of the story ? no memorisation possible for any of the tab libraries ? (unless you explicitly do the state handling and css yourself)

Comment: @Konrad isn't it strange that all popular tab libraries for react that I tried destroys and recreates ? reactjs is there for a long time and all these libraries are freaking popular. why haven't anyone thought of memoization ? I feel both you and me are missing something .

Answer (score 0):

As @joepvl nicely explains here [react-tabs/issues](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs/issues/547#issuecomment-1935061460)
the default behaviour indeed removes and re-adds to DOM tree as @Konard was saying. And this is common in most tabs library for react(that I experimented with).

So there is a option called `forceRender` that will eager load all DOMs and also maintain the full DOM tree in memory. But if you have lots of tabs eager loading may slow you down.

The desired solution uses combination of own state variables and `forceRender` param of [react-tabs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs) . I'll copy @joepvl 's code for the sake of completing this answer:

```
function PostMountPersistedTabs() {
  const [renderedPanels, setRenderedPanels] = useState([0]);

  const onSelect = useCallback((index) => {
    setRenderedPanels((renderedPanels) =>
      renderedPanels.includes(index)
        ? renderedPanels
        : renderedPanels.concat(index)
    )
  }, []);

  return (
    <Tabs onSelect={onSelect}>
      <TabList>
        <Tab>0</Tab>
        <Tab>1</Tab>
        <Tab>2</Tab>
      </TabList>
      <TabPanel forceRender={renderedPanels.includes(0)}>Panel 0</TabPanel>
      <TabPanel forceRender={renderedPanels.includes(1)}>Panel 1</TabPanel>
      <TabPanel forceRender={renderedPanels.includes(2)}>Panel 2</TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```